# Can I get malware from a .rar file without opening it in Android?

Tags: malware, android, zip

I was on a group with almost 200k people on it in Telegram. One of these members (probably new, his account is now deleted) sent me (and to other people too) a file named "Customer deposit H.rar", I proceeded immediately to delete it and analyze my Android 9.0 phone with Kasperky Free.

What are the possibilities that I'm infected if I didn't open the file (I didn't analyze the file, I'm assuming this has malware on it)?

In other words, and as the title says, can I get malware from a .rar file without opening it in Android?

I found another question about this but always refers to Windows.

Comment: Not unless there are some not known vulnerabilities in the android or the archive software, that will allow this to happen.

Comment: Agreed with mrSotirow, however was the .rar actually an archive? Or was it executable code (just with a .rar extension)?

Comment: Thanks for answers, @RocketSEA sadly, I don't know, I just remember that it's size was around 394 kb, as the first post said, I literally "panic" and almost immediately deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a vulnerability in File Explorer's archive manager, it's harmless. Even if a malware compromises File Explorer, it cannot break out of [app-sandbox](https://source.android.com/security/app-sandbox) without another vulnerability. Simply uninstalling the app removes the malware.

To compromise system, an embedded malware needs chain of critical vulnerabilities and even then there's no assurity that the exploit will run because SELinux blocks process execution that violates SELinux policy. You can verify that your system hasn't been tampered with by simply rebooting your device. Tampered image bricks the device on boot because of [Android Verified Boot](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md).